# How to find Scala method

Tags: scala

Using the Scala API : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4 is there a way to find the object or class associated with a method ?

So if I just know that there exists a method "println" is there a quick way to navigate to the details of this method at API location ? (other than searching the Scala source)

Comment: I know it doesn't really answer your question, but `println` is specifically defined in `Predef`, where lots of automatically-imported stuff is found: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.10.4/#scala.Predef$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on one of those letters under the search box and you'll be taken to an alphabetical list of functions.  From there you can search for the one you're interested in and you'll be given a list of all functions with that name and a link to their definition.

Comment: thanks, yes that works. would be nice to just type name of function and side panel displays functions that match.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that's in there by default (i.e. without an import) comes from `scala.Predef` or the `scala` package. Otherwise you can look for the imports. Perhaps the most pragmatic answer is to click through in a scala IDE (ctrl-click or F3 in eclipse/scala-ide, probably similar in IntelliJ).